# Run an application with/as screensaver

Tags: windows-7, windows, screensaver

How do I add a custom application to run as a screensaver. Like calc.exe for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was easy: rename `Calc.exe` to `Calc.scr` and it will appear in the Screen Saver Dialog box. But not all EXEs will work.

**EDIT:** Not all EXEs work in the `C:\Windows\System32\` folder, but those that did not work there, work in the `C:\Windows\` folder. These were the ones that depended on external DLLs. Something I noted, but I don't know how or why that is.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as the solution @laggingreflex. It helps the community.